# How to reuse some of the functions present in the Nuxt 3 parent project within the child project which is extending the parent?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I have 2 Nuxt 3 projects: ProjectA and ProjectB, which are present in the same root folder. My `ProjectB` extends the `ProjectA` to reuse some of the common components and pages. This works as expected.

```
root
     --ProjectA
     --ProjectB
```

I need to use some of the functions present within the `nuxt.config.ts` of the `ProjectA` within `ProjectB` but for some reason, I am unable to access them and reuse them. Is there a way I can achieve this directly without needing to use additional libraries?

`ProjectA/nuxt.config.ts`: This contains some functions to obtains different logo, css and favicon based on the environment variables

```
function getTheme(theme: string){
  return `~/assets/themes/${theme}/css/main.css`;
}

function getLogo(theme: string){
  const baseUrl = process.env.NUXT_APP_BASE_URL || '';
  return `${baseUrl}themes/${theme}/images/logo.png`;
}
```

`ProjectB/nuxt.config.ts`: This extends the ProjectA but I want to reuse the methods present in `ProjectA/nuxt.config.ts`:

```
    // auto import components
  components: [
    {
      path: '~/components',
      pathPrefix: false,
    },
    {
      path: '../ProjectA/components',
      pathPrefix: false,
    },
  ],

  extends: '../ProjectA',
```

Is there a way I can reuse the methods in ProjectA within ProjectB nuxt.config.ts without needing to use additional libraries or copying the code again in ProjectB?

Comment: for better practice, consider using nuxt layers and a monorepo management system like pnpm workspace

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add path for autoimport if it's not in current project directory.

```js
{
      path: '../ProjectA/components',
      pathPrefix: false,
},
```

While you certainly can try to import your methods manually and it would work, it's not a preferable way though.

If you use `ProjectA` as a container for base stuff such as pages, components, etc. it would be better to convert it to a library in another git repository
ProjectA will be the core library from which you could import everything you want.

And then, referring to the documentation (https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/auto-imports#auto-import-from-third-party-packages) you can add auto import functionality to `ProjectB` using `ProjectA` as a third party lib